# How to fetch specific MySQL fields values into defined placeholders?

Tags: php, arrays, security, loops, pdo

Can somebody advise me how to fetch MySQL values into defined placeholders. I am building custom CMS and stuck with lack of PHP knowledge.

My SQLTable:

```
`menuLinkID` smallint(5),
`menuLinkDescription` text NOT NULL,
`menuActualLink` mediumtext NOT NULL,
```

1) Index.php (Where I am defining functions);

```
// Build Index page:
function IndexFunction() {
$results = array();
$results['pages'] = $data['results'];
```

2) Include.php (My default template which should populate required links)

```
<div id="text1"><a href="<?php echo $menuActualLink1; ?>"><?php echo $menuLink1; ?><span>&raquo;<?php echo $menuLinkDesc1; ?></span></a></div>
<div id="text2"><a href="<?php echo $menuActualLink2; ?>"><?php echo $menuLink2; ?><span>&raquo;<?php echo $menuLinkDesc2; ?></span></a></div>
<div id="text3"><a href="<?php echo $menuActualLink3; ?>"><?php echo $menuLink3; ?><span>&raquo;<?php echo $menuLinkDesc3; ?></span></a></div>
```

3) myClass.php (Class which actually does all job)

This where I am stuck. I nearly managed to display all records, but this is not my goal.
My goal would be fetch all records to fill all my placeholders (so I believe loop statment would be required in this situation)

```
public static function getList( $numRows=1000000, $order="menuLinkID ASC" ) {
$conn = new PDO( DB_dsn, DB_Uname, DB_pass );
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, menuLinkID AS id FROM myTABLE
        ORDER BY " . mysql_real_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";

$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->execute();
$list = array();
```

I am not sure how to accomplish this. I would appreciate if you could advise me about this.

Comment: have you tried [bind_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is very hard to get into your structure (which seems quite unusual), but I'd try.

```
public static function getList() {
    global $conn; //connect somewhere else and use one connection everywhere
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM myTABLE ORDER BY menuLinkID ASC";
    $st  = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->execute();
    return $st->fetchAll();
}
```

(you could also define PDO connection in the constructor and thus use `$this->conn` instead of global)

then in the index

```
$data['menulinks'] = $yourClass->getList();
```

then in the template

```
<?php foreach($data['menulinks'] as $i => $row): ?>
<div id="text<?php echo $i+1; ?>">
  <a href="<?php echo $row['menuActualLink1']; ?>">
    <?php echo $row['menuLink1']; ?>
    <span>&raquo;<?php echo $row['menuLinkDesc1']; ?></span>
  </a>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```